# Oracle SQL Command line does not stay open

Tags: oracle

I have install oracle express edition but SQL command line does not stay open so,how do I establish database connection?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run `sqlplus`. In that case, open a command prompt; type `cmd` from `start -> Run`. In the opened command prompt execute the sqlplus executable which mostly would be in `ORACLE_HOME\bin\*` directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can use database home page which is a web_browser based interface. search for - "goto database home page". it will redirect you to the database homepage.